# JavaScript sorting array by name

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am sorting an array contains objects. I am sorting the last name based on alphabetical order.
But when I print out, only the first item of the sorted array appear and it filled the array.
What is mean is array =[{name: "White, David", score:100},{name: "Bee, Axis", score:101}]
after sorting by last name the array becomes array =[{name: "Bee, Axis", score:101},{name: "Bee, Axis", score:101}], all the information are the same. I don't know what was wrong?

here is to populate the array:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    record.Customer= customerName[i];
    record.MonthlyCharge = monthlyCharge[i];
    record.PastDueAmount = pastDueAmount[i];
    record.DaysPastDue = numDaysPastDue[i];
    records.push(record); 
    
    table += `<tr>`;
    table +=`<td>${record.Customer}</td>`;
    table +=`<td>$${record.MonthlyCharge}</td>`;
    table +=`<td>$${record.PastDueAmount}</td>`;
    table +=`<td>${record.DaysPastDue}</td>`;
    table +=`</tr>`;
}
tableBody.innerHTML = table;
```

To sort the array

```
nameColumn.addEventListener("click", function (){
    records.sort((a,b)=>a.Customer.localeCompare(b.Customer));
    updateTable();
});

function updateTable()
{
    let table = "";
    for (let record of records)
    {
        table += `<tr>`;
        table +=`<td>${record.Customer}</td>`;
        table +=`<td>$${record.MonthlyCharge}</td>`;
        table +=`<td>$${record.PastDueAmount}</td>`;
        table +=`<td>${record.DaysPastDue}</td>`;
        table +=`</tr>`;
    }
    tableBody.innerHTML = table;
}
```

Comment: Are `customerName`,  `monthlyCharge`,  `pastDueAmount`, and `numDaysPastDue` separate arrays and you have to build an array of objects every time? Or do you already have an array of objects?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies in the code that populates the table. You are always referencing the same record object and changing its values every time. That's why all records appear to have the values of your last input. Here's how it should be:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // you need to instantiate a new record if it's a class or simply create a new object
        record = {}
        record.Customer= customerName[i];
        record.MonthlyCharge = monthlyCharge[i];
        record.PastDueAmount = pastDueAmount[i];
        record.DaysPastDue = numDaysPastDue[i];
        records.push(record); 
        
        table += `<tr>`;
        table +=`<td>${record.Customer}</td>`;
        table +=`<td>$${record.MonthlyCharge}</td>`;
        table +=`<td>$${record.PastDueAmount}</td>`;
        table +=`<td>${record.DaysPastDue}</td>`;
        table +=`</tr>`;
    }
    tableBody.innerHTML = table;
```

Comment: Or use object literal syntax and `var` to ensure correct scoping: `var record = { Customer:  customerName[i], MonthlyCharge: monthlyCharge[i], PastDueAmount: pastDueAmount[i], DaysPastDue: numDaysPastDue[i] };` You should probably use `var` (or `const` in more recent browsers) in any case...

Comment: Appreciate your help